# Resolve Url By Means of Git

Tags: git, url, config

In respect to git configuration kind of

```
[url "git@gitlab.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
[url "https://bitbucket.com/other/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/some/
```

Git can change the remote repo source and the way to fetch it for specific url.

So having some specific repo url how one can resolve the target url git eventually would using to clone the repo (without actually cloning it).

So that

```
https://github.com/some/repo.git => https://bitbucket.com/other/repo.git
https://gitlab.com/any/repo.git => git@gitlab.com:any/repo.git
https://bitbucket.com/no/change.git => https://bitbucket.com/no/change.git
```

In theory this could be done with some pipe series of `grep`/`sed`/`awk` etc on a `git config --get-regexp ...` command

Yet how to achieve the same by means of `git` it self without adding extra custom logic and purely in the way `git` is doing this
e.g. something like

```
git resolve-remote https://github.com/some/repo.git
```

Or maybe with some workaround still without actually involving the `git clone` command.

Comment: I think the question is valid and interesting. My advice is to ask the question again with more details: what configuration you have and what do you want from Git. Something like: "*I configured `git config url.xxx.insteadof yyy`, I have URL `yyy/repo`, how do I get the same URL Git would use to `git clone yyy/repo` but without cloning? I'd like to receive `xxx/repo`, is there any way in Git to get it without accessing remote repo?*"

Comment: The edited question is quite good but I cannot answer it because it's closed. @daniel-a-white can I ask you to reopen the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a simple command to resolve a remote URL configured with `url..insteadOf`. But I found a way using a transient empty repository. Create a new repository, configure URL rewriting (global or local; for the following examples I use local), add a remote, ask Git for the rewritten URL, remove the repository. Example:

```bash
$ cd /tmp
$ git init _repo.tmp
$ git -C _repo.tmp config url.git@gitlab.com:.insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
$ git -C _repo.tmp config url.https://bitbucket.com/other/.insteadOf https://github.com/some/
$ git -C _repo.tmp remote add remote1 https://github.com/some/repo.git
$ git -C _repo.tmp remote add remote2 https://gitlab.com/any/repo.git
$ git -C _repo.tmp remote add remote3 https://bitbucket.com/no/change.git
```

Let's verify:

```bash
$ git -C _repo.tmp config --local --get-regexp "^remote\..*\.url"
remote.remote1.url https://github.com/some/repo.git
remote.remote2.url https://gitlab.com/any/repo.git
remote.remote3.url https://bitbucket.com/no/change.git
```

The URLs are not rewritten in the config. Now the magic: `git remote get-url` prints the rewritten URL:

```bash
$ git -C _repo.tmp remote get-url remote1 
https://bitbucket.com/other/repo.git

$ git -C _repo.tmp remote get-url remote2 
git@gitlab.com:any/repo.git

$ git -C _repo.tmp remote get-url remote3 
https://bitbucket.com/no/change.git
```

Clean up:

```bash
$ rm -rf _repo.tmp
$ cd # HOME
```

I can create a shell script but its disadvantage is — it will create/remove one repository per URL. That could be slow if you gonna check many URLs. For many URLs create one repository, add remotes, get rewritten URLs and then remove the repository.

Comment: Thanks a lot @phd. Such a great Idea. As well I found a way to run this even in bulk. I marked your answer as accepted. Still you can refer my answer for others in your post to profit from the improvement as well.

Comment: As well thanks for your advice to push my question further, so that didn't miss your great idea))

Answer (score 1):

Its is brilliant @phd. This is exactly the way I expected to find!!!!
And it really works!!!

Even disadvantage you mentioned I can see could be hacked

As we don't really care repo data to be that consistent we can compose its config manually without invoke `git` it self.

So that

1. Prerequisites

```bash
git --global config url.git@gitlab.com:.insteadOf https://gitlab.com/
git --global config url.https://bitbucket.com/other/.insteadOf https://github.com/some/
```

2. Compose in bulk input urls config

```bash
git init ~/tmp/remotes
get-source-urls-list \
   | awk '{ printf "[remote \"r%s\"]\n  url = %s\n", NR, $1}' \
   >> ~/tmp/remotes/.git/config
```

This would add in bulk remotes into config (regardless of its amount) in a view of

```
[remote "r1"]
    url = https://github.com/some/repo.git
[remote "r2"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/any/repo.git
[remote "r3"]
    url = https://bitbucket.com/no/change.git
```

3. And next just query all the mapped urls as follows

```bash
git -C ~/tmp/remotes remote  -v \
  | awk '/\(fetch\)/ {print $2}'  # print only fetch url to rid of duplicates
```

Which results in

```bash
https://bitbucket.com/other/repo.git
git@gitlab.com:any/repo.git
https://bitbucket.com/no/change.git
```

Thank you!!!